# width and height of a rectangle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rect

In JavaScript, when we increase or decrease the value entered into the width of a rectangle, do the changes in the output rectangle happens only from the right side?
If I explain my doubt more precisely, I saw that when I increase the width, the rectangle stretches out in the right direction. The size of the rectangle change, and it happens from the right side only. When reduced, it stretches in. Which means the width of the rectangle becomes small. but it also happens from the right side of the rectangle. so I want to know if this's always this way for the 'width'?

And also when I change the height, the changes only happen from the below part of the rectangle. the upper part never stretches. so is it always the below part?

Can I please know what's the reason for this? and if it's the same everywhere when I code in JS.

Comment: JavaScript does not have rectangles. What are you talking about, dom elements, canvas rectangles, something else?

Comment: @Bergi I started taking lessons at khan academy. and I started with the unit intro to JS. isn't it about JavaScript? there were lessons about shapes and colors etc.

Comment: They probably pre-defined a `Rectangle` class then for you to play around with. Unless you haven't already, in a later lesson they'll probably introduce that code and/or make you write it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the GUI always regards top-left point as default position.
That's why you get kinda result on changing width or height.
It's same in MFC, API, WPF, Canvas and major platforms.